# $.ajax() processing my url encoded string

Tags: jquery, ajax, urlencode

I have a url encoded string i'm sending to php via the jQuery [**AJAX**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) API that appears to be getting automatically decoded and passed to the server.

### Ajax Call:

```
var requestXML = '<searchString>red%20ford%5BimpoundState%3Ain%5D</searchString>';
$.ajax({
 data: "query=" + requestXML,
 success: function(response)
 {
     //alerts <searchString>red%20ford%5BimpoundState%3Ain%5D</searchString>
     alert(requestXML);
 }
});
```

Inspecting the request in the chrome dev tools shows its being decoded[image]

I'm a bit lost here, I read a bit about jQuery processing data, but i turned that off via `{processData: false}` but i got no results.

-Thanks for any help!

### UPDATE:

My backend is currently set up to parse xml with url encoded values.

Like: `<searchString>red%20ford%5BimpoundState%3Ain%5D</searchString>`

When i pass `data: {query: requestXML}` i get...

This:`%3CsearchString%3Ered%20ford%5BimpoundState%3Ain%5D%3C%2searchString%3E` (url encoded xml).

The real issue is when i'm generating this XML I encode the values, but jQuery seems to decode them in the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data: {query: requestXML},` to pass the parameters and they get url encoded by jQuery.

The point is the the param gets attached to the url as-is if it already a string.

Quote

> **data** (*Object, String*)
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is
>   converted to a query string, **if not
>   already a string**. It's appended to the
>   url for GET-requests. See processData
>   option to prevent this automatic
>   processing. Object must be Key/Value
>   pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery
>   serializes multiple values with same
>   key based on the value of the
>   traditional setting (described below).

Since you use `GET` method, your params get added to the URL string. The decoding then happens from the browser and not from jQuery.

Comment: no... i'm not using the get method. although my code doesn't reflect this (not all ajaxoptions are included), I'm explicitly setting it to post in the ajax call.

Comment: @Derek.. hmmm. You still use the `{processData: false}` ?